# Adding a custom shortcode to Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add a new Shortcode to replace/Add the Tracking code in Woocommrce, all woocommrce shortcodes are defined by a php class

I added a new shortcode name woocommerce_my_order_tracking (can see below), how can I do the same thing I did without running over the Woocommrce templates files.

```
class WC_Shortcodes {

/**
 * Init shortcodes.
 */
public static function init() {
    $shortcodes = array(
        'product'                    => __CLASS__ . '::product',
        'product_page'               => __CLASS__ . '::product_page',
        'product_category'           => __CLASS__ . '::product_category',
        'product_categories'         => __CLASS__ . '::product_categories',
        'add_to_cart'                => __CLASS__ . '::product_add_to_cart',
        'add_to_cart_url'            => __CLASS__ . '::product_add_to_cart_url',
        'products'                   => __CLASS__ . '::products',
        'recent_products'            => __CLASS__ . '::recent_products',
        'sale_products'              => __CLASS__ . '::sale_products',
        'best_selling_products'      => __CLASS__ . '::best_selling_products',
        'top_rated_products'         => __CLASS__ . '::top_rated_products',
        'featured_products'          => __CLASS__ . '::featured_products',
        'product_attribute'          => __CLASS__ . '::product_attribute',
        'related_products'           => __CLASS__ . '::related_products',
        'shop_messages'              => __CLASS__ . '::shop_messages',
        'woocommerce_order_tracking' => __CLASS__ . '::order_tracking',
        'woocommerce_my_order_tracking' => __CLASS__ . '::my_order_tracking',
        'woocommerce_cart'           => __CLASS__ . '::cart',
        'woocommerce_checkout'       => __CLASS__ . '::checkout',
        'woocommerce_my_account'     => __CLASS__ . '::my_account',
    );
```

And later in the class

```
    public static function order_tracking( $atts ) {
    return self::shortcode_wrapper( array( 'WC_Shortcode_Order_Tracking', 'output' ), $atts );
}
public static function my_order_tracking( $atts ) {
    return self::shortcode_wrapper( array( 'WC_Shortcode_My_Order_Tracking', 'output' ), $atts );
}
```

How can I register this shortcode (as a woocommerce shortcode with all the other $attr woocommerce shortcode get) but without running over the templates file in Woocommerce,

Answer (score 1):

You use [`add_shortcode()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) in your theme's `functions.php` or preferably in a site-specific plugin.

```
add_shortcode( 'woocommerce_my_order_tracking ', 'so_46027030_tracking_shortcode' );

function so_46027030_tracking_shortcode( $atts ) {
    return 'your code here';
}
```

Comment: Did you catch that this OP is **just overriding woocommerce core files**…

Comment: Yes, but I think the question was "how do I avoid overriding core files"?